# SpotLight Node Turns Everything Pitch Black

Tags: godot

I am a beginner in Godot and I am making a 3D scene. However, when I added a SpotLight node to the scene, all the other objects turned dark. The OmniLight and the DirectionalLight works fine. When I hide the SpotLight, the scene returns to normal. If the SpotLight isn't facing the objects, they remain how it is supposed to be. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Here is what it looks like.

[image: Here is what it looks like.]

When I make it not visible:

[image: When I make it not visible:]

Oh, and these objects are CSG objects, just so you know.

[Here is the link to the minimal repro project.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/631kbi3cu0laikb/Min_repro.zip?dl=0)

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you post a minimal reproduction project?

Comment: What do you mean by "post"? How can you post a godot project into a question?

Comment: One option is to reduce it down to one tscn file by making any scripts and resources built-in and copy and paste it either on your OP or to something like [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/). Second option is to zip the minimal project and upload it to cloud file service, e.g. dropbox, drive, etc and link it here. Third option, is to upload your project to a git service and link it here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I added the minimal project.

Comment: When I used Godot 3.2 to open it, it fixed the problem, so maybe there was a problem with the Godot version??

Comment: I also have this bug when I add a meshinstance to a scene—the grid disappears, even though the grid is enabled. Then, when I add a material to it, the grid reappears, but when I instance it to a scene, the material is black. When I add a specific node to the scene, the materials return to normal. I think this has something to do with this.

Comment: This appears to be a [known issue](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/30330) on Intel integrated graphics. Try switching to the GLES2 renderer in the top-right corner of the editor.

Comment: That just made it worse. When I switched it to GLES2 the materials became permanently black. The lights are barely visible. Is there another solution?